# How to write ‎\leftrightarrow with a line below

Tags: arrows

I would really appreciate if someone could tell me how I can ‎‎`\leftrightarrow` with a line below like this?

[image]

I tried ‎‎`\leftrightarroweq` but it didn't work.

Comment: The command `\leftrightarroweq` requires the package `stmaryrd` or `boisik`.

Comment: It work if you add the package `stmaryrd`: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\begin{document}
$\leftrightarroweq$
\end{document}`

Comment: @SandyG Thank you so much. It works.

Comment: @dexteritas Appreciate you. I've done what you told and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build your own symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\leftrightarroweq}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\leftrightarroweq@\relax}}
\newcommand{\leftrightarroweq@}[2]{%
  \vtop{
    \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\leftrightarrow$}%
    \ialign{%
      \hfil##\hfil\cr
      \copy\z@\cr
      \noalign{\nointerlineskip\kern0.7\ht\z@}
      \makebox[\wd\z@][s]{$\m@th#1\relbar\hss\relbar$}\cr
      \noalign{\kern-0.7\ht\z@}
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a \leftrightarroweq b \leftrightarrow c$

$\scriptstyle a \leftrightarroweq b \leftrightarrow c$

$\scriptscriptstyle a \leftrightarroweq b \leftrightarrow c$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Compare with what you get with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\begin{document}

$a \leftrightarroweq b \leftrightarrow c$

$\scriptstyle a \leftrightarroweq b \leftrightarrow c$

$\scriptscriptstyle a \leftrightarroweq b \leftrightarrow c$

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't think you want this.

Answer (score 3):

The command `\leftrightarroweq` requires the package `stmaryrd` (or `boisik`). If you don't want to load all the glyphs, you can use the `only`option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[only,leftrightarroweq]{stmaryrd}

\begin{document}

$A\leftrightarroweq B$

\end{document}
```